# unable to get list of culprits to send email in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Below script is working fine and its getting list of culprits

```
 def PostFailure()
 {
 emailext body: "your email body here",
                     mimeType: 'text/html',
                     subject: "your subject here",
                     to: emailextrecipients([
                         [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']
                     ])
}
```

I have formatted the body section of email as mentioned in below code and class CulpritsRecipientProvider is not working.

```
 def PostFailure()
 {               
    def x='1'
    def config = [:]
    def subject = config.subject ? config.subject : "EPBCS ${env.JOB_NAME} - Release Number:${env.ReleaseNumber} Build #${env.BuildNumber} - ${currentBuild.result}!"
    def content = '${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html-ps.template"}'
    def attachLog = (config.attachLog != null) ? config.attachLog : (currentBuild.result != "SUCCESS") // Attach buildlog when the build is not successfull
    to: emailextrecipients([
    [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
    ])
}
```

Please help me to fix the code which is not working.

Comment: You haven't called `emailext body: ...` in your revised code. As a side note, you can use the Elvis operator instead of the Ternary operator to set defaults. For example,  `def attachLog = (config.attachLog != null) ? config.attachLog : <default_value>` can be written as `def attachLog = config.attachLog ?: <default_value>`.

Comment: I got this but I am unable to load template into variable content

Comment: Where are you calling the variable in your code?

Comment: def content = '${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html-ps.template"}'

Comment: I mean, where while calling the plugin? It must be something like `emailext body: '$content' ...,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script worked for me.

```
def postFailure()
 {                
   def content = '${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html.template"}'

    emailext body: "${content}",
    mimeType: 'text/html',
    subject: "this is subject",
    to: emailextrecipients([
    [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']
    ])
}
```